# how to Check for the particular child tag inside multiple parent tag

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have to check a particular child tag  inside the multiple parent tag (

I have code to check child tag inside the single parent class but in my case, that code is not helpful

```
<div class="company-cat-group"
   <ul> ==$0
       <li>
          <i class="cultivation-icon"></i>
       </li>
```

the parent tag(`<div class="company-cat-group"`) is repeated multiple times  and in every parent tag I have to check that child tag (`<i class="cultivation-icon">`) is present or not

Comment: Do you intent to verify all the parent `<div class="company-cat-group">` tag contains the child tag `<i class="cultivation-icon"></i>`?

Comment: yes, i have to also handle if the child tag is not present

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Java**

You can use `List` to collect the parent elements you mean, and extract them one by one using `loop`.

Then try find element in an element, selenium provided it.

Try the below code:

```
List<WebElement> elements = driver.findElements(By.className("company-cat-group"));
for(WebElement element: elements) {
    List<WebElement> child = element.findElements(By.className("cultivation-icon"));
    if(child.size()>0) {
        System.out.println("present");
    }
}
```